# Using axios for Register form in React. The onSubmit button is not being read. The onChange button is not being read

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am building my first ecommerce website. I am trying to setup a register/login/logout form with react using an axios get call to a my my mongodb database.
I am having trouble setting input values for form submission. I am pretty sure that i dont have the handle change function setup correctly. I think it would be easier to bring in user data and destruction it but i am not not sure on how to implement a spread operator.

```
const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  
  const handleChange  = (e) => {
    console.log(name);
    setName (e.target.name);
    console.log(email);
    setEmail(e.target.email);
    setPassword(e.target.password)
    console.log(password);
  }
'''<div>
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
         <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            value={name}
            placeholder="Enter name"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
        </div>
```

Comment: 1. It looks like your code has a typo, though it's not clear whether that's your problem or you just copied & pasted to your code block incorrectly. Your function is initialized as `OnChange` and yet you pass a non-existent `onChange` to the input element.

Comment: 2. Can you post your entire component's code? It'd be best if you could post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but any more context here would go a long way.

Comment: I am fairly new to react and I am not sure i understand how to answer your question. I am having trouble setting the values for my user information.

Comment: To set the value in state from an event in an input you must use "event.target.value". Try console logging "event.target.password" or "event.target.email". These will be undefined because those properties do not exist on the target element. However, as Alfonso has shown in his example, you can assign a "name" to an input element (this is the "event.target") and from there, you can conditionally set state.

Answer (score 0):

The 'onChange' references a single input (e.target is your input). Your input has a `name`and a `value`. You don't have  `email` inside your input, for example.

You must get the `value` of your input,  not email (doesn't exists).

So, a working example will be like this:

```js
const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  
  
  const handleChange  = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "name") {
       setName (e.target.value);
  } else if (e.target.name === "email") {
       setEmail(e.target.value);
   } else 
    setPassword(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

Or, much better:

```js
const RegisterScreen = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const handleChange  = (e) => {
     const newData = {...data}
     newData[e.target.name] = e.target.value
     setData(newData)

  }

}
```

A working component will be:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const RegisterScreen = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    const handleChange  = (e) => {
       const newData = {...data}
       newData[e.target.name] = e.target.value
       setData(newData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
         <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={data.name}
            placeholder="Enter name"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
         <input
            type="password"
            name='password'
            value={data.password}
            placeholder="Enter password"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
          <input
            type="email"
            name='email'
            value={data.email}
            placeholder="Enter email"
            required
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></input>
          <div>
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      name: {data.name}
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      password: {data.password}
                  </li>
                  <li>
                        email: {data.email}
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RegisterScreen
```

Fully working app on https://github.com/afoone/stackoverflow_answer_-70325367

Comment: I understand the condtional statement the best but how do I make the input dynamic in the form. value={name} ,value={email},value ={password} dont set state. The information doesnt stay on the page.

Comment: I've improved my answer and a working example